# sudo -l and sudo -ll output

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, sudoers

`sudo -l` gives me output:

```
User test may run the following commands on server:
(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/vim /usr/bin/motd
```

`sudo -ll` gives me output:

```
Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: root
    Options: !authenticate
    Commands:
        /usr/bin/vim /usr/bin/motd
```

When i run as user 'test': `sudo /usr/bin/vim` I get error:

`Sorry, user test is not allowed to run '/usr/bin/vim' as root on server.`

I have a feeling this is due to the fact that usr/bin/vim is symlinked to another file `/usr/bin/vim -> /etc/alternatives/vim`

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out I misinterpreted the `sudo -l` command. This message:

```
User test may run the following commands on server:
(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/vim /usr/bin/motd
```

means that the only command that can be run without password is `vim` with `/usr/bin/motd` as an *argument*. It doesn't mean `vim` or `motd` can be run freely.

I feel like an idiot :D

Comment: You've figured it out, good job! Next time please post actual, unedited output in your question :)